# What is asyncio.PriorityQueue's default priority?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, priority-queue

Does `asyncio.PriorityQueue` have a default priority? If I do not give a priority value with an entry, will it default to FIFO? Apologies if this is a duplicate, I have been searching for this answer everywhere and haven't found it yet.

I have a discord music bot that currently uses `asyncio.Queue` to hold song info, and am debating switching to a priority queue to add a "play next" option. I have struggled to find detailed descriptions of `asyncio`'s priority queue implementation.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#priority-queue): _"retrieves entries in priority order (**lowest first**)"_. Lowest means according to the natural (Python) order of the items. Therefore (again from the docs): _"Entries are typically tuples of the form (priority_number, data)"_. So, you're supposed to make your own priority if the natural (Python) order isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the regular [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) uses a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to store the items under the hood, the [`asyncio.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.PriorityQueue) uses a `list` with the [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) implementation from the standard library. ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L218))

The [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) documentation should give you all the info you need to know about how this works, but in short there is no "default" priority configured anywhere. The heap methods will simply use the rich comparison operators (`<=`, `>=` etc.) on the items to maintain invariance.

That is why the `PriorityQueue` docs suggest using 2-tuple items with the first element ensuring the ordering.

Tuples support rich comparison by proxy of their elements. And that comparison is **lazy**. That means, when comparing two tuples `tup1` and `tup2`, the first check compares `tup1[0]` and `tup2[0]`. And if that check returns a clear order, the other elements are not even checked.

Try this:

```py
from asyncio import PriorityQueue

class Foo:
    pass

q = PriorityQueue()
q.put_nowait(Foo())
q.put_nowait(Foo())  # error
item = q.get_nowait()
print(item)
```

You will get an error as soon as you try to add a second `Foo` instance because there is no way to order objects of the class `Foo`.

But do this instead:

```py
...
q = PriorityQueue()
q.put_nowait((2, Foo()))
q.put_nowait((1, Foo()))
item = q.get_nowait()
print(item)  # (1, <__main__.Foo object at 0x...>)
```

This will work and get you the tuple with the `1` as the first element because `1 < 2`.

If you make the first elements ambiguous, you will again get an error:

```py
...
q = PriorityQueue()
q.put_nowait((1, Foo()))
q.put_nowait((1, Foo()))  # error again
```

But as soon as you add a [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) method to `Foo`, the priority queue will accept multiple instances just fine (because the `heapq` functions will) and set up their priority corresponding to their ordering with the `<` operator:

```py
from asyncio import PriorityQueue


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:  # just for easier demonstration
        return f"Foo({self.value})"

    def __lt__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, Foo):
            raise NotImplementedError
        return self.value < other.value


q = PriorityQueue()
q.put_nowait(Foo(2))
q.put_nowait(Foo(1))
item = q.get_nowait()
print(item)  # Foo(1)
```

So in short, you simply need to ensure that whatever items you put into the `PriorityQueue` *can* be ordered and that their order reflects the priority you want to establish.